# Мигает изображение при зуме в FireFox 45

Tags: html, css, css3, firefox, css-animation

Применение свойства `transform: scale3d` вместе с `transition` на изображениях в FireFox 45+ может вызвать нежелательную перерисовку и "мигание":

```css
.hoverPop {
  transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.42, 0, 0.42, 1.75);
}
.hoverPop:hover {
  transform: scale3d(1.2, 1.2, 1.2);
}
img {
  border: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.imgwrap {
  width: 65px;
  margin: 0 auto 12px auto;
  height: 65px;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgwrap">
  <img class="hoverPop" src="http://i1175.photobucket.com/albums/r631/Bananafarma/testIcon_zpsfrhmw5qd.png" alt="test">
</div>
```

Как иправить нежелательное поведение и заставить картинку анимироваться плавно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решается следующим образом:

```
img {
   image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
}
```