# Уменьшение масштаба сайта, возможно ли?

Tags: html, css

Добрый день, уважаемые знатоки:)
Вопрос на засыпку. Имеется сайт. Но не устраивает масштаб всего сайта в целом. Уменьшаю масштаб сайта до 70-75% путем CTRL - и картинка устраивает.
Возможно ли сделать уменьшение масштаба сайта через CSS итд не прибегая к изменению размера всех блоков. Тоесть чтобы грузился не 100% масштаб а 75% к примеру.
Спасибо заранее.

P.S. Нужно кроссбраузерное решение...

Comment: по идее zoom должен помочь http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-zoom (для firefox можно использовать `-moz-transform: scale(2); -moz-transform-origin: 0 0;`

Answer (score 1):

Измените масштаб body

```
body {
   -webkit-transform: scale(0.75);
   -moz-transform: scale(0.75);
   -ms-transform: scale(0.75);
   transform: scale(0.75);
   -webkit-transform-origin: center 0;
   -moz-transform-origin: center 0;
   -ms-transform-origin: center 0;
   -o-transform-origin: center 0;
   transform-origin: center 0;
}
```

Comment: Сработало,Спасибо! Но теперь бэкграунд поплыл :(

Comment: ну, значит, он неправильно был настроен.

Comment: Вот очень непростой в верстке сайт http://polati.zephyrlab.ru/   Поставьте там в браузере вот такие стили для body, как в ответе. И увидите, что все работает

Comment: @AndrewFoxis для картинок попробуйте image-rendering: optimizeQuality

Answer (score 1):

На `body` добавьте свойство `zoom`:

```
body {    
  zoom: .75 
}
```

Работает даже в IE 8.

Вот только данное свойство в **FireFox** не сработает. Для него можно сделать полифил:

```
body {
   -moz-transform: scale(.75);
   -moz-transform-origin: center 0;
}
```

Однако `transform` в FF может повлиять на отрисовку картинок. Для исправления этого советую воспользоваться решением из этого [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/619747/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B5-%D0%B2-firefox-45):

```
img {
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality
}
```