# Системный масштаб и адаптивная вертска

Tags: html, css, flexbox

В моем приложении адаптивная верстка реализована с помощью Flexbox и медиа запросов. При изменении размеров окна, все отрабатывает корректно, элементы меняют свой размер все окей. Однако целевой пользователь, пользуется корпоративными ноутбуками, у которых системный масштаб по умолчанию 125%. Соответственно в браузере все увеличивается, разрешение по сути остается прежним и элементы не влезают. Появляется вертикальный скролл. Если вручную уменьшить масштаб до 80%, то все становится окей. Какое лаконичное решение тут можно придумать?

[image: Системный масштаб 100%, браузерный масштапб 1920x1080]

1 скриншот - Системный масштаб 100%, браузерный масштаб 100% 1920x1080
2 скриншот - Системный масштаб 125%, браузерный масштаб 100% 1920x1080

[image: Системный масштаб 125%, браузерный масштаб 100% 1920x1080]

Comment: добавлю, что достаточно убрать вертикальный скролл, чтобы по высоте все влезало

Comment: Вы можете, например, для десктопов принудительно запретить вертикальный скролл `html, body { overflow: hidden}`

Comment: в таком случае, часть контента просто скроется, мне такой результат не нужен)

Comment: На приведённых Вами скринах внизу нет никакого контента - что именно скроется?

Comment: если выбрать обращение слева, то справа будет подобие мессенджера, и не будет видно даже input-а,

Comment: тогда посмотрите в сторону [изменения масштаба body](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/632071/%D0%A3%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%88%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8)